# How should I properly compare my array index value against array length

Tags: c#, arrays

Say I have an array that has 5 values `int[] gear = new int[] {5,4,3,2,1};` and I also have a variable that I use to get the value I want `int currentGear = 0;` Now I would like to step through the array under a certain condition with this code:

```
if(rpm > shiftRPM && currentGear < gear.Length)
  currentGear++;

Console.WriteLine( gear[cuurentGear] );
```

However, using that code I am able to go past the array length because gear.Length is 5, but array's are zero indexed(i.e. the max number I can have is 4).

So my solution is to just add 1 to currentGear in the if statement, but this for loops works as expected:

```
for(int i=0; i<gear.Length;i++;)
  Console.Write(gear[i]);
```

And outputs: `5 4 3 2 1` with no errors.

Also, if I `Console.Write(gear.Length);` it outputs `5`, so clearly my error is with my if statement allowing my index to pass gear.Length since 4 < 5 and 5 is out of range.

Is there a better way to increment my array index variable than doing this:

```
if(rpm > shiftRPM && (currentGear+1) < gear.Length)
  currentGear++;
```

or is that the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is basically the best way. The maximum value of an index is in fact Length-1, not Length, so when you only check that currentGear is less than Length, you are not really guarding against it getting too large.

Comment: Works for me, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing another method. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

why not initialize  currentGear as:

```
var currentGear = -1;
```

Comment: This will not avoid the potential for his index to go too high, except by luck.